# Django signals for new entry only

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I'm using Django's post_save signal to send emails to users whenever a *new* article is added to the site. However, users still receive new emails whenever I use `save()` method for already created articles. How is it possible to receive emails only when NEW entry was added?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `post_save` signal receives a boolean `created` argument which indicates if the saved `instance` was created.

```
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        print('Instance is new')
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

There actually is an argument passed with the signal "created: A boolean; True if a new record was created".

I think, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for instance.id is a nice way of determining if the instance is "new". This only works if you use ids that are auto-generated  by your database.

Comment: Won't work on a post_save signal IIRC - by that time the instance already have an id.